# Understanding of Absolute Values

Tags: absolute-value

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two functions.

Does the following property hold true?
$$|f(x) - g(x)| = |g(x) - f(x)|$$

On the surface, it would seem like it, but then some other properties of absolute values don't seem to hold.

$$|f(x) - g(x)| \le a$$
$$-a \le f(x) - g(x) \le a$$

But this doesn't seem to be equivalent to the following
$$|g(x) - f(x) | \le a$$
$$-a \le g(x) - f(x) \le a$$

Why doesn't the property $|f(x) - g(x)| = |g(x) - f(x)|$ hold true?

Comment: Why do you think $-a\leq f(x)-g(x)\leq a$ isn't equivalent to $-a\leq g(x)-f(x)\leq a$? "Seem" isn't good enough ;)

Comment: I guess that's a good point.  I just tried to find some values of $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $a$ that would provide a counter-example to the above property being true and haven't been able to find any.  I know that's far from proof that none exists.  Does there exist a proof that shows that the above holds true?

Comment: Yes, there's a proof... can you think of anything you might do to one inequality to turn it into the other?

Comment: @symplectomorphic Thank you, that question helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the following property hold true?

Yes. $$|a-b|=|-(b-a)|=|-1||b-a|=|b-a|,$$ for any $a,b\in V$, where $V$ is normed vector space, and $|\cdot|$ is norm (which is absolute value if $V=\mathbb{R}$) on $V$.